# scheduling a notification in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I developed a reminder app and i used timer.performWithDelay function to call the function in which i specified the tasks to be done. it works fine on the simulator. i want to run it on device for that i need to use system.scheduleNotification .
I am unable to understand how to use it and check in simulator. i'm sharing the code that i've written.

```
local function onComplete( event )
print( "index => ".. event.index .. " action => " .. event.action )

local action = event.action
if "clicked" == event.action then

if 2 == event.index then --pressing snooze and setting snooze time to 1mins
audio.stop()
print("**SNOOZED**")
forAlarm1 = timer.performWithDelay (60*1000, compareTime)

elseif 1==event.index then --pressing ok and setting the alarm to repeat mode
print("**ALARM SET TO REPEAT**")
audio.stop()
end
end
```

end

```
function compareTime()
print("CompareTime is called")
timer.performWithDelay (7*24*3600*1000, compareTime)
audio.play(alarm)
local alert = native.showAlert( "Garbage Collection Reminder", "It's Time", { "OK",     "SNOOZE" },onComplete)

end

forAlarm = timer.performWithDelay (delay*1000, compareTime)
```

Can somebody please tell me how should i modify my code to run it on the device???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. it can be done using the below code
    local options = {
               alert = "Alert!!!",
                 badge = 2,
               sound = "alarm.caf",
            }

```
        -- schedule using seconds from now
        local notification = system.scheduleNotification( delay, options )


        local listener = function( event )
                local notification = system.scheduleNotification( 7*24*3600*1000, options )
            local alert = native.showAlert( "Garbage Collection Reminder", "It's Time", { "OK", "SNOOZE" },onComplete)

        end

        Runtime:addEventListener( "notification", listener )
```